# How to send muliples values to a method and recived multiple values in different vars in Java

Tags: java, variables, return-type

Hello there I am new in Java and I am  locking a way to send multiples parameters to a method but this method need to return some values too , example:

`var1,var2,var3 = convertTonegative(varx,vary,varz);`

So in this case after some check into the method this method need to return 3 values to each var,  means:

varx after checked assign the value to var1

vary after checked assign the value to var2

varz after checked assign the value to var3

I just create a class that can received any values, but I do not how to return those values.

```
public class converToNegative{
    
    public converToNegative(String... args) {  // Constructor
        convertAll(args);
    }
    
    private String[] convertAll(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++){
            if (args[i].equals("") || args[i] == null) {
                args[i] = "-1";
            }
        }
        return args;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why can't you encapsulate all the three into a class and return the reference of the same?

Comment: No it doesnt work that way, you need to use a POJO to return multiple values. Else, you would probably want to pass mutable objects as the parameter to your method, and change the contents of the objects inside the method

Comment: Java does not support this kind of unpacking.

Comment: Your question sounds as if you have experience of Python, which automatically packs/unpacks variables into/out of tuples, thus making the syntax look as if a function is returning multiple values. In fact, even in Python, a function only returns a single value. Java doesn't have tuples, but you can hold your variables as fields in a class and then return an instance of that class. By the way, you should use conventions like class names are nouns and methods are usually verbs. Class names start with a capital letter, and methods with a small letter.

Comment: You should take a look at [Records](https://www.baeldung.com/java-record-keyword).

Answer (score 0):

I get what you're looking to do. In my early days with learning Java, I also wanted to do the same, but always felt that this is a missing feature in the language.
But later I realized that while this adds complexity to the syntax of the language, the task can still be achieved without returning multiple values from the method.

Personally, I feel the best way to do this would be using Streams. You could just stream a list, use a mapping function to modify the values if conditions are met, and return back the list.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] list = new String[]{"1", "2", "3", "-5", "", null};
        List<String> processedList = Arrays.asList(list).stream().map(num -> (num!=null && num!="") ? num : "-1").collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println("processedList: " + processedList);
    }
```

But if you're just learning Java, or want to do it using the same approach, I guess there's no other way but to refactor the code to call the method one by one for all the arguments. Something like this:

```
public class converToNegative{
    
    public converToNegative(String... args) {  // Constructor
        convertAll(args);
    }
    
    private String[] convertAll(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++){
            args[i] = convert(args[i]);
        }
        return args;
    }
    
    private String convert(String num) {
        if (args[i].equals("") || args[i] == null)
            return "-1";
        else
            return num;
    }

}
```